# Get year of previous and next months

Tags: php, date

In my calendar, I need to compare the current year to the years of previous and next years to find out if the month needs to reset back to January, and the year incremented/decremented. I already have this to get the next & previous months:

```
$prev_month = date('F',strtotime("last month"));
$next_month = date('F',strtotime("next month"));
```

Does anybody have any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance - Tanner.

Comment: Just noticed, your next and prev are maybe the wrong way around in the you assign the "last month" expression to the $next_month variable. Not sure: you might be going back in time. Anyway, might catch you out further down the line if you've got them the opposite way from you expected so I thought I'd mention.

Comment: @ADW: Whoops, thanks. I copied/pasted, so I didn't write the code, ps. Wouldn't want someone to think I wrote that, I'm not that smart :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$next_month_y = date('Y',strtotime("last month"));
$prev_month_y = date('Y',strtotime("next month"));
```

Comment: Sheesh! I woulda never thought of that! Thanks! I'll accept in 12 mins.